# Using socat to make a secure tcp connection to an irc server

Tags: networking, tcp, socat, irc

Recently, I got into irc, so I installed [`sic`](https://tools.suckless.org/sic/) and started - obviously - chatting.

But, it turns out that `sic` doesn't provide any security features like SSL or TCP so I in `man sic`, they told to use `socat` to establish a secure TCP  connection so I installed it and read the documentary.

In the example section, I found this:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:www TCP:www.domain.org:www`

So I just ran 

`socat tcp-listen:6667,fork tcp:irc.freenode.net:6697`

and tried to connect with it using `sic -h 127.0.1 -p 6667` which puked out:

`sic: remote host closed connection`

with `socat` not complaining.

---

I tried it again with the option `-d -d` for `socat` being more verbose:

```
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1889] N accepting connection from AF=2 
127.0.0.1:38664 on AF=2 127.0.0.1:6667
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1889] N forked off child process 1897
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1889] N listening on AF=2 0.0.0.0:6667
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] N opening connection to AF=2 
185.30.166.37:6697
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] N successfully connected from local 
address AF=2 192.168.178.28:42822
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] N starting data transfer loop with FDs 
[6,6] and [5,5]
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] W read(5, 0x558eefca3710, 8192): 
Connection reset by peer
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] N socket 2 to socket 1 is in error
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] N socket 1 (fd 6) is at EOF
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] N socket 2 (fd 5) is at EOF
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1897] N exiting with status 0
2019/01/02 00:38:38 socat[1889] N childdied(): handling signal 17
```

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](https://freenode.net/kb/answer/chat)

Comment: i've got `ca-certificate` installed and tried connecting at `chat.freenode.net` which didn"t work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socat tcp-listen:6697 openssl-connect:irc.freenode.net:6697`

and then

`sic -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6697 -n your-nickname`

But really you shouldn't be using **sic** unless you have a specialized need.

Try [irssi](https://irssi.org/) instead -- it will save you much time and provide many features that sic does not.

Once open, you can just run `/connect -ssl irc.freenode.net 6697`, being sure to replace with your own connection details. You can also create custom configurations to auto-connect to various servers and channels on start-up.